# How to call MySQL function from Spring Data repositories

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I need to call MySQL `funtion()` from a `org.springframework.data.repository` which will return a `String`.

I am able to execute query using `@Query` annotation on top of my interface method declaration, but i have no idea to call a function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose you have a function named `echo` which takes a string as its input and return the same string as part of the output:

```
CREATE FUNCTION echo(to_be_echoed TEXT) RETURNS TEXT;
```

Then if you want to call this function from your repository, you can use a *Native Query* with the following SQL:

```
SELECT function_name(arguments)
```

Hence, your repository method would be like:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT echo(?1)", nativeQuery = true)
String echo(String toBeEchoed);
```

Comment: What if it returns a List?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring Data, you can use one of these functions:

```
@Procedure("prosedure_name")
void prosedureName();
```

or

```
@Procedure(value = "prosedure_name")
void prosedureName();
```

or

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "prosedure_name")
void prosedureName();
```

or

```
@Procedure
void prosedure_name();
```